# Bottle 'o enchanting recipe using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a crafting recipe for xp bottles in Minecraft 1.13. I've made the recipe, and I've got a command block that removes xp when you craft it:

```
/experience add @a[scores={xp=1}] -7 points
```

- The xp objective is simply minecraft.crafted:minecraft.experience_bottle
- Another command block removes the score afterwards
- I'm removing 7 points because 1 bottle gives between 3 and 11 points so I took the rough average as a compromise

Now I'm trying to figure out how to stop people from doing it when they have no xp.
I was thinking a system that removes the xp bottle from your inventory after crafting if you don't have any xp, but I don't know how to go about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hm, sadly the `experience` command always succeeds, no matter if it can remove the experience or not. That's definitely a bug, I'll report it. Edit: It is already reported: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-121651

Comment: You can use `/experience query` and `execute store result`. I'm so glad right now that this isn't a 1.12 question and I don't have to mess with `/stats`. :D

Comment: Oh wait, this is much easier than I thought: There's an `xp` scoreboard type.

Comment: @Nik3141 You're right, even the same number of points is wanted. Weird.

Comment: This one's older...

Comment: @FabianRöling Actually I think mine is technically a duplicate of this one because as TQ pointed out this one is older, but the name of this one is much different so I'd say leave both alone or mark mine as a duplicate.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that yours was from 2019 and this one from 2018. Anyway, the other one has more and better answers, so it should be ok to backwards resolve. And that the name is different doesn't matter. The reason to not delete duplicates is so that people can find one and get directed to the other, so having a different wording in the duplicate question is actually a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

There's an `xp` scoreboard type. So you just have to create a scoreboard like this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add scoreboardName xp {"text":"scoreboardDisplayName"}
```

Then you can query for the score being 7 or more like this: `@a[scores={scoreboardName=7..}]`

---

If you already have players with XP when you set up this command system, then you can put their current XP value into the scoreboard like this:

```
/execute as @a store result score @s xp run experience query @s points
```

Comment: This will be useful to test for it, but you can still craft the item as it is basically a crafting recipe in a data pack. I still need a way to stop people from getting it, maybe by deleting the bottle once it's in the inventory but I don't know how to do that

Comment: That's just the `/take` command. Or, if you want to completely prevent the crafting, you can turn the limited crafting gamerule on, give everyone all recipes and then take the XP bottle recipe from them. I'll edit the answer tomorrow when I'm on a PC again.

Comment: I take it you mean the /clear command? If so, I completely forgot about that one. Though the problem with that would be, how do I get it to wait till the item is in your inventory? And not execute right after you crafted the item?

Comment: Ummm... Yeah, I don't know how I fantazised the "take" command, that never existed. Yes, I meant "clear". You could make an advancement that's triggered by an inventory change. But that doesn't prevent players from throwing out the item, maybe giving it to another player. So maybe you should actually prevent crafting it completely.

Comment: Query for the levels, not the points, because at 1 level you have 7 points. Points query gives points from the last integer level, so it might not let you craft it successfully if you have say 33 levels and 2 points. Also, like @FabianRöling said, crafting has too many loopholes. Use a system where throwing a bottle onto a cauldron or enchanting table kills the bottle and gives the closest player a bottle of enchanting while removing 7 xp points. It is cleaner, easier, and less prone to exploitation.

Comment: The asker asked about points. Of course you can easily add a second command with an `xp=1..` selector.

Comment: @Fabian I'm aware. However, levels are related to points, and points can give unexpected/undesirable results, so levels may be a better option, which I'm offering to the asker. If I do `/xp query @s points` with just over 6 levels, it will say that Nik3141 has 2 xp points. In this case, I have enough xp to do the transaction, but the scoreboard will not allow me to. If you test for the player having more than 1 level (as you said with `xp=1..`), you automatically know they have enough points because they have at least 7 xp points.

Comment: That's what I meant, you just worded it better just now. You can check for 7+ points with my method and 1+ levels with your method and just allow it for both.